# Assembly: Loop to pop up from Stack

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm messing around with Stacks Push and Pops in Assembly MIPS. I'm only able to pop the data from the stack `$sp` manually by changing the index of the pointer, but how do to this using a loop?

Example:

```
lw $t1, 0($sp) ## pops the first data at index 0
lw $t1, 4($sp) ## pops the second data at index 4
lw $t1, 8($sp) ## pops the third data at index 8
addui $sp, $sp, 12 ## Lets free our stack
```

now my problem is, how to do this in a loop? if I used the following

`addui $sp, $sp, 4` it will means free 1 space in our stack. It will not mean that Increment the stack pointer to the next index.

I hope you guys get what I'm trying to say here.

I don't think using $t2 is allowed here `lw $t1, $t2($sp)`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Firstly, those `lw`s do not "pop" the stack, they loads from the stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addiu $sp, $sp, 4` **does** mean increment the stack pointer by 4 (which is the size of a word). If you want a loop, you can do:

```
    li $t0, 3            # loop counter
loop:
    lw $t1, 0($sp)       # load top of stack
    addiu $sp, $sp, 4    # free top of stack
    # ...                # do something with $t1
    addiu $t0, $t0, -1   # decrement loop counter
    bgtz $t0, loop       # repeat if not 0
```